# Пул соединений для Spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Нужно создать свой пул соединений для Spring jdbcTemplate, поддерживающий lazy concurrent loading, и который будет создаваться как Spring Bean. 
Я так понимаю, что это как минимум нужно имплементить DataSource, внутри которого, методы getConnection будут вызывать, методы какого-то класса пула управляющего соединениями. Только мне непонятно, как этот класс должен с этими соединениями работать, если у этого DataSource нет никаких методов по возвращению соединений в пул, как управлять соединениями, они разве не закончатся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне не очень понятно, что значит **lazy concurrent loading** в твоём контексте, но создать `DataSource` как Spring-бин довольно таки легко:

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
  //тут создание
}
```

Реализация своего пула скорее всего будет напрасной работой, т.к. уже есть свободные библиотеки, решающие эту проблему. К примеру тот же [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) или [Apache commons dbcp](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/index.html)

Что касательно возврата соединений в `DataSource`. Внутри `DataSource` действительно нет никаких подобных методов. Однако они есть внутри `Connection`. Интерфейс [Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) реализует интерфейс [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). Следовательно по окончанию использования объекта с типом `Connection` разработчик обязан вызвать метод [Connection#close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()). В этом методе как раз и должна лежать логика возврата соединения обратно в пул `DataSource`.

Comment: я так понял, что под lazy concurrent loading имеется ввидy, thread safe lazy initialization, а так большое спасибо.

Comment: @Serghius объекты типа `Connection` впринципе не должны быть потокобезопасными из-за логики своего использования. Вызов же `DataSource#getConnection` в указанных библиотеках является потокобезопасным.